# How to filter JSON data by URL parameter?

Tags: json, filter, get

Lets say if I am looking to filter by id=2 in the browser's URL. This is currently not working (retrieving all the data instead):

```
/stories?id=2
```

This is my json file:

```
{
"stories": [
  {
    "id": 0,
    "title": "Puss In Boots",
    "subtitle": ""
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Aladdin",
    "subtitle": ""
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Sleeping Beauty",
    "subtitle": ""
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "Puppy Dreams",
    "subtitle": ""
  }
]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

(if you need vanilla js only, here is the solution)

I create a simple function that gets the ID from the URL, then access the correct id in JSON, and shows the title inside a div.

change the `?id=` to see the changes

```js
const data = {
  stories: [{
      id: 0,
      title: "Puss In Boots",
      subtitle: "",
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "Aladdin",
      subtitle: "",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "Sleeping Beauty",
      subtitle: "",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: "Puppy Dreams",
      subtitle: "",
    },
  ],
};

const card = document.getElementById("card");

setText(data, card);

function setText(data, element = document.body) {   // element if there isn't then we get the body instead
  const id = getUrlParams().id ?? 0;                // if url is ?id=2 then it will return 2, if undefined then 0
  const base = data.stories[id];                    // change this if the structure is different or changed.

  myAppLogic();

  function myAppLogic() {                           // put here all your logic
    element.textContent = base.title;
  }
}

function getUrlParams() {
  let result = [];                                  // [] empty array at the start

  const stringArray =
    location.search                                 // "?id=number&other=string&another=string" , this get the last part of the URL
    .substring(1)                                   // delete the "?" character from the location.search
    .split("&");                                    // ["id=number", "other=string", "another=string"]

  stringArray.forEach((string) => {
    result.push(
      string.split("=")
    );
  });                                               // [[id, number], [other, string], [another, string]]

  return Object.fromEntries(result);                // {id: number, other: string, another: string}
}
```

```css
#card {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="card"></div>
```

Comment: I was looking for filtering by id during the (GET) request itself before I loaded the data on JavaScript/React.js, but I will go with your answer as it works well. Thank you!!